# Google fonts not working with SCSS - Font-family compiles in main.css file but is not included when site loads

Tags: html, css, sass, fonts

Having this problem with SCSS and google fonts.

When I compile my SCSS files into main.css I see that the font-family is there -
[image]

However, when I go to run my local server the font doesn't load and is not included in the main.css file -

[image]

Not sure what is going on as I have included the google font links in my index file,

[image]

and did an import in my main scss file.

[image]

Any ideas of why the font-family is on the main.css file but is ignored when the server loads it?

Comment: Please include all code as text formatted as code, not images of text, which cannot be read by visually impaired humans, nor search engine bots. See [ask] for more tips that help prevent questions from getting downvoted and closed.

Comment: Looks like a browser cache problem.

Comment: @LSE you are correct LSE, I just tried in FFOX and it worked. I tried making a change to something basic and it wasn't taking effect so I suspected it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I usually include fonts as imports in scss partial:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700");
```

then in my vars.scss I will define a variable something like this:

```
$font-default: "Nunito Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, -apple-system;
```